# Oracle Error (exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit)

Tags: .net, oracle

I have a .Net application with Oracle database. I received the below error while trying to run a report in my application. Request anyone to check and advice if there is a fix for this problem. 
Also note that I have spoken to my DBA and he says that there is something in the .Net code that is not ending the sessions.

The error message is :

ORA-2391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit

Let me know if you need any more info

Comment: You should *close/dispose* your sessions somewhere.

Comment: Don't you use connection pools?

Comment: First check that the limit makes sense.  Find the limit with statements like these:  `select username, profile from dba_users;`, `select * from dba_profiles where resource_name = 'SESSIONS_PER_USER';`.
  Look at `select username, status, v$session.* from v$session;` to see where your sessions are coming from.  For example: are other people using the account, are some of the sessions "SNIPED" or "KILLED" (these sessions don't always go away quickly), or is anybody using parallelism (in some environments a single user can easily consume hundreds of sessions.)

Comment: @OracleUser If you're doing a traditional client-server application, where would you use a connection pool? Each client executable would simply make a direct connection to the database.

Comment: Are you using ODP .NET or System.Data.OracleClient?